# Manually plot GLM predictions with unscaled values

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm, predict, glmmtmb

I have a model with two variables, crop and pop,
both have scaled values.

I am using GLMMtmb to run a model on it,
but I'm unsure how to manually plot predictions from this model, backtransforming the scaled variable values.

A chunk of data is at the end of the post for a reproducible example.

so for my data frame columns:
Animal is the presence or absence of the animal, crop and pop the variables that may affect presence or absence.

So I run the model

```
model <- glmmTMB(animal~crop+pop,family="poisson",data=dummy)
```

I received some code from someone to manually plot predictions but it's not working.
This is the code, for for example, the 'pop' variable.

```
range <- range(dummy$pop)

nd <- expand.grid(pop = seq(range[1], range[2], by=0.5))

dummy <- as.data.frame(predict(model, newdata=nd, se.fit=TRUE))
dummy$lower <- dummy$fit - 1.96*dummy$se.fit
dummy$upper <- dummy$fit + 1.96*dummy$se.fit

dummy$fit_trans <- plogis(dummy$fit)
dummy$low_trans <- plogis(dummy$lower)
dummy$up_trans <- plogis(dummy$upper)
dummy <- cbind(dummy, nd)
```

this should then give me a dataframe I can feed to ggplot, but it goes wrong where I create the object 'nd' (newdata). Something needs to be added there but I'm unsure what.
Additionally, I don't see in this code where my variable data is unscaled before creating the new data frame?

```
structure(list(animal = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), crop = structure(c(-0.911367192804466, -0.656468577561402, 
0.937306298620515, -0.748068186743915, -0.950289715380232, -0.950289715380232, 
-0.311140903098454, -0.950289715380232, -0.420299555068266, -0.204030814471523, 
0.50447619733435, -0.950289715380232, -0.777918539996587, -0.950289715380232, 
-0.950289715380232, -0.840253112662893, -0.839667809844811, -0.949704414301948, 
-0.950289715380232, -0.332797072571516, -0.950289715380232, 0.28586616195498, 
-0.950289715380232, -0.949704414301948, -0.950289715380232, -0.217785406339271, 
-0.950289715380232, -0.949704414301948, -0.950289715380232, -0.950289715380232, 
-0.950289715380232, -0.917220203587303, -0.950289715380232, -0.950289715380232, 
-0.950289715380232, -0.950289715380232, -0.683099761835028, -0.950289715380232, 
-0.950289715380232, -0.950289715380232, -0.950289715380232, -0.950289715380232, 
-0.950289715380232, -0.420006934975588, -0.950289715380232, -0.86512840935985, 
-0.950289715380232, -0.880053585986186, -0.950289715380232, -0.947070559449672, 
0.886092437742609, 1.83281709105803, 1.11640850164685, -0.950289715380232, 
-0.946485258371388, 1.37335566631441, -0.126771093015647, -0.949704414301948, 
-0.896734664107575, -0.123551937954986, -0.826498527754337, -0.950289715380232, 
-0.307921748037792, 1.68180931195255, 0.606903807743094, -0.190568898369987, 
-0.669052549874602, 1.74970429966619, -0.941217548666834, 1.81701382450034, 
0.217678665495733, -0.235637069219248, 0.166464804617827, -0.949411763762807, 
-0.945022005675679, 0.0827666616935611, 0.362833263318178, 1.5957700969398, 
0.778982349115678, 1.85652176820044, 1.54836074265497, -0.950289715380232, 
0.153588184375181, 1.1480148120681, -0.950289715380232, -0.860153345844944, 
-0.551699672370031, -0.916927552178262, -0.791673117945951, -0.949704414301948, 
-0.580672067915984, 1.70053900213117, 0.212703567184868, 0.465553605166667, 
-0.490535698380696, 0.512963070798555, -0.40449645553117, -0.949704414301948, 
0.437459181245815, 1.78921202067216, -0.939168994892841), dim = c(101L, 
1L)), pop = structure(c(-0.197547924591922, -0.194351971156629, 
-0.188274258566538, -0.196448483438051, -0.197547924591922, -0.197534996338939, 
-0.197544742856045, -0.19666972080707, -0.184138726259079, -0.187096628792688, 
-0.181474291574343, -0.197126836606957, -0.191909922110918, -0.197541385064299, 
-0.197547924591922, -0.180014490953617, -0.196345541198624, -0.194080008065368, 
-0.197547924591922, -0.169718619816262, -0.1973883809182, -0.19069419228899, 
-0.19750465288443, -0.197547924591922, -0.197547924591922, -0.196222722433591, 
-0.197547924591922, -0.197007381120755, -0.197547924591922, -0.197547924591922, 
-0.197547924591922, -0.196084866482173, -0.196199779840005, -0.197547924591922, 
-0.197547924591922, -0.196775288017525, -0.195128528488411, -0.197547924591922, 
-0.197547924591922, -0.196661275901739, -0.197547924591922, -0.197547924591922, 
-0.197547924591922, -0.195309309220705, -0.197547924591922, -0.196083127378007, 
-0.197547924591922, -0.197047712962236, -0.197547924591922, -0.19661973821873, 
0.624878194166003, -0.194073305851747, -0.165976797458507, -0.197547924591922, 
-0.189654680869701, -0.138488532034927, -0.182502054986232, -0.151862484978888, 
-0.146757177620867, -0.180411925114601, -0.196752195942981, -0.197416680215279, 
-0.183794718471439, -0.173372247384172, -0.196556998242149, -0.174186298469269, 
-0.178206794332005, -0.197547924591922, -0.196558496041342, -0.182985603845477, 
0.0359655292697121, 0.14216237743388, -0.170265068895674, -0.197547924591922, 
-0.19328285943275, -0.148427554030811, -0.115746893472626, -0.189714944074946, 
-0.185416997205207, -0.1959619567473, -0.0975791931695816, -0.197326675563388, 
-0.17579755900438, -0.0809452064393561, -0.197246026550915, 0.888153565621317, 
-0.189168753981969, -0.193326520514112, -0.191939980937669, -0.197547923770278, 
-0.193648598847386, -0.140792688570448, -0.162820943186907, -0.0971587686665226, 
-0.184731765563276, -0.166566876527242, -0.0244512966150544, 
-0.19624995376397, -0.147791915216302, -0.167901037976233, 16.3965287744725
), dim = c(101L, 1L))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 3786L, 3787L, 3788L, 
3789L, 3790L, 3791L, 3792L, 3793L, 3794L, 3795L, 3796L, 3797L, 
3798L, 3799L, 3800L, 3801L, 3802L, 3803L, 3804L, 3805L, 3806L, 
3807L, 3808L, 3809L, 3810L, 3811L, 3812L, 3813L, 3814L, 3815L, 
3816L, 3817L, 3818L, 3819L, 3820L, 3821L, 3822L, 3823L, 3824L, 
3825L, 3826L, 3827L, 3828L, 3829L, 3830L, 3831L, 3832L, 3833L, 
3834L, 3835L, 3836L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the best way is to not rescale variables before running a model, but supplying scale(variables) to the model formula. This way, when you create a new data frame for predictions, the values are automatically unscaled.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.

1. If you are only measuring presence / absence of animals, then you need a logistic regression rather than a Poisson regression (i.e. you should have `family = "binomial"` in your model).
2. It's not clear why you are using `glmmTMB`, since you have a fixed effect only model, meaning that base R's `glm` would do just as well.
3. The main issue with your prediction data frame is that your model needs values for both `crop` and `pop`, but you are only supplying values for `pop`
4. In your dummy data frame, there is a single extreme outlier for `crop` which means that equally-spaced values across the whole range are not representative of your data.
5. It is difficult to visualise predictions with upper and lower confidence intervals if you have two dependent variables.

To get a 2D grid of probability predictions over varying values of `crop` and `pop`, we can do

```r
library(glmmTMB)

model <- glmmTMB(animal ~ crop + pop, family = "binomial", data = dummy)

nd <- expand.grid(crop = seq(min(dummy$crop), max(dummy$crop), length = 10),
                  pop  = seq(-0.2, -0.15, length = 10))

preds <- predict(model, newdata = nd, se.fit = TRUE)

nd$pred  <- plogis(preds$fit)
nd$lower <- plogis(preds$fit - 1.96 * preds$se.fit)
nd$upper <- plogis(preds$fit + 1.96 * preds$se.fit)

head(nd)
#>          crop  pop      pred     lower     upper
#> 1 -0.95028972 -0.2 0.8231875 0.6957251 0.9045785
#> 2 -0.63842177 -0.2 0.7764348 0.6327054 0.8750293
#> 3 -0.32655383 -0.2 0.7215021 0.5445071 0.8488165
#> 4 -0.01468589 -0.2 0.6589997 0.4379221 0.8273954
#> 5  0.29718206 -0.2 0.5904329 0.3280019 0.8098054
#> 6  0.60905000 -0.2 0.5181596 0.2299935 0.7947321
```

When it comes to plotting, we can show the prediction grid as a `geom_tile` as follows:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(nd, aes(crop, pop, fill = pred)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c("Probability of\nAnimal presence") +
  coord_fixed(60) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

If you really want to see the confidence bands, you will need to use facets:

```r
ggplot(within(nd, pop <- factor(paste("pop =", round(pop, 3)))),
              aes(crop, pred)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ pop) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your extensive reply. I was wondering, would there not be a way to have one plot showing 'Pred' on the Y-axis and the unscaled values of only one of the variables on the x-axis?

Comment: @Beardedant yes, that's what the second plot shows. If you only want one panel, then you can predict at the median value of `pop` to show how the prediction changes with changing values of `crop`. We can't unscale your data because scaling isn't reversible. Do you _need_ to scale your data in the first place?